# LabView - unable to permanently change string value, what can be the reasons?

Tags: controls, labview

I received an abandoned student LabView project I need to adapt. There is one VI which contains an array of two controls with length 30. I need to change the strings in several places within that array which is possible as long as I do not close the vi. If I close and reload the vi the previous values are there again, saving the changed values as default does not help. Cutting the connection to the type def did not help either.
There is also no databinding and I could not find any mechanism that might lock the values. It must be something obvious to experienced LabView developers, but I could not find anything on the net. 
What can be the reason that the values cannot be changed permanently?

Edit:
After playing around for a long time, i found out that I have to set as default value on the array, and not on the individual positions in the array. That solved it, simple problem, several hours spent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around for a long time, i found out that I have to set as default value on the array, and not on the individual positions in the array. That solved it, simple problem, several hours spent...

Comment: I would like to, but there is a 24h limit (i think only for new users) i can do so in 2h